# How to filtering datetime column for hours interval (just hours) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
datetimecolumn      valuecolumn
2017-01-03 01:00    17
2017-01-04 02:55    4
2017-01-04 05:55    4
2017-01-04 12:55    9
2017-01-04 16:55    88
2017-01-05 17:53    1
2017-01-06 10:22    74
2017-01-06 15:22    111
```

Now I need only the rows in which the hour is between 12:00 and 18:00.
That would be:

```
datetimecolumn      valuecolumn
2017-01-04 12:55    9
2017-01-04 16:55    88
2017-01-05 17:53    1
2017-01-06 15:22    111
```

How can I apply that filter?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you don't want to change column `datetimecolumn` format, so convert it to datetime and assign to `s`. Subtract `s` from its `floor('D')` to get only time portion and compare them with `between` to create a boolean mask `m`. Finally, slicing `df` using `m`

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.datetimecolumn)
m = (s - s.dt.floor('D')).between(pd.Timedelta('12:00:00'), pd.Timedelta('18:00:00'))

df.loc[m]

Out[190]:
     datetimecolumn  valuecolumn
3  2017-01-04 12:55            9
4  2017-01-04 16:55           88
5  2017-01-05 17:53            1
7  2017-01-06 15:22          111
```